# Missing/Dropped 302 redirects on cloud run

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, http-redirect, http-status-code-302

We have a system that 302 redirects users to different other websites based on several criteria and we have big-query analytics & grafana that help us visualize the business.

The system is getting about 35k requests a day, and we noticed that there's 2.5-3% difference between our providers and what we actually get. So every 100 requests the provider is logging, we only get 97-98. We wanted to verify where the issue is, so we redirected all the traffic to ourselves before passing it on, and again we see another 2.5-3% of requests. This is not related to unprocessed analytics events as we're looking at data from 24 hours ago.

It seems like some of the redirects get dropped for some reason. We're 100% sure it's not inside the system itself. We added logs, metrics and what not, and we're sure that every request we get is properly logged and analyzed. Running stress tests from a single computer of up to 100 rps all accepted and logged

Is it common that 302 redirects get dropped so much?

Relevant technologies we're using:

1. Cloud Run with custom domain (we increased min instances to prevent possibility of dropped due to scaling issue)
2. Cloudflare - DNS only to google servers
3. Express - No cache header

Thought I'm considering but found no evidence of:

1. Some ISPs/Google might very briefly cache requests
2. Some browser issues, dropping some redirects or sharing some 302 redirects - but very unlikely
3. There's still some problem with our app

Any thought/help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by **302 gets dropped**. An HTTP 302 Location response is a **hint** to the client to go to a new location and repeat the request. Cloud Run, DNS, Load Balancers, etc. do not interfere with HTTP responses nor do they drop them. If they did you would have an entirely different problem (requests would not complete).

Comment: I mean that when I redirect to a different route under my own domain, about 2-3% redirects do not reach that endpoint, and that's my problem.. I don't get how is that possible or if that is a common/known thing..

Comment: Are you using Cloud Load Balancers  to make sure when someone navigates to the app's URL, they are redirected to a different route? If yes, what you have done so far (include your Dockerfile, app.json, app.js). Also just have a look if your [Cloudfare is working correctly with your original web server.](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000219871-Troubleshooting-redirect-loop-errors-). Last but not the least, its could be something on your client, go through your application code and routes/redirects if they are set properly. There is no report of Cloud Run dropping redirects